# UISegmentedControl and localization

Tags: localization, ios6, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `.xib` file, with accompanying `.strings` files for different languages. The `.xib` file contains a label, and a `UISegmentedControl`.

When asking IB to localize the `.xib` file, I get the following `.strings` file:

```
"6.segmentTitles[0]" = "title1";
// ...More strings related to the segmented control...
"11.text" = "bla";
```

The 'bla' string belongs to the label.

Changing the 'bla` string is reflected in runtime, while changing the 'title1' string does not. Anyone knows why?

Comment: There's this [OpenRadar](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2159402) but it hasn't been triaged yet.

Comment: 9 years later this bug is still there.

Answer (score 4):

This question is not new, but as it is still without any answers I will add my solution as it may help others.

Generally, as it's mentioned above, it is an open bug that UISegmentedControl segment titles do not pick up localization strings.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    // Locale will be picked automatically by NSBundle.
    NSString *resourcePath  =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MainStoryboard" ofType:@"strings"];
    NSDictionary *resourceDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath];
    [self.segmentedControl setTitle:[resourceDict objectForKey:@"COo-BO-Ryl.segmentTitles[0]"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [self.segmentedControl setTitle:[resourceDict objectForKey:@"COo-BO-Ryl.segmentTitles[1]"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];

}
```

Where `COo-BO-Ryl` is the Object ID of segmentedControl.

Not very pretty, but does the job.

Comment: In his code OP used the xib version, and in my I used the storyboard version, but otherwise the solution should work.